# Count sphenic odd number in range efficiently

Tags: algorithm, primes, number-theory

I couldn't find a good solution for this problem;
I need to count the number of sphenic odd number in a range efficiency I have used sieve algorithm but normally there should be a better way to do this.

an odd sphenic number is a product of 3 distinct odd prime number.

I have tried with this but it takes so much time.

```
char t[200000001];
int dp[200000001];
int main() {
    cin.tie(0);
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
   for(int i=3;i<200000001;i+=2)
   {
       if(t[i]==0)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<200000001;j+=i)
                t[j]++;
        }
        if(t[i]==3 && i%2)
            dp[i]=1;
   }


    for(int i=100;i<200000001;i++)
        dp[i]+=dp[i-1];

    int test=0;
    cin>>test;
    for(int tt=1;tt<=test;tt++)
    {
        int a,b;
        cin>>a>>b;
        cout<<dp[b]-dp[a-1]<<"\n";
    }

}
```

thank you

Edit:
I am trying to solve this problem:
http://codeforces.com/group/HtnK54FR7R/contest/219854/problem/D

Comment: I don't understand the output examples in the linked problem statement. How could the answer be 0 for the interval (1, 100)?

Comment: @גלעדברקן the smallest sphenic odd number (or magic number, according to the problem) is 3*5*7 = 105, which is greater than 100.

Comment: @EvilTak ah, tx :)

Answer (score 1):

A prime sieve starting at 3 is a great idea. But the highest possible useful prime is ...? (hint: 200,000,000 / (? * ?))

One possible way might be to enumerate combinations of two primes backwards as the primes are generated, binary-searching the highest index for the second and the lowest possible index for the third, exiting the generation altogether if `15 * current_prime` is greater than `r`.